When Are PostgreSQL Session-Level Settings "Reset" on a HikariCP ProxyConnection?
To preface, we are using HikariCP 5.0.1 with Java 21. I have also looked through the following questions (and many more) and did not find my answer:

Connection timeouts with HikariCP
Best approach for returning connection objects to HikariCP pool
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1633
Hikari CP connections are suddenly invalidated

As well as reading through the wiki and multiple source files for HikariCP: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP
I have recently been tasked with implementing a performance improvement for my company's platform. The overall issue we were seeing was that on large operations (spanning multiple DB transactions), we spent ~10 seconds executing statements that adjust the lock_timeout, statement_timeout, and idle_in_transaction_session_timeout session-level settings in the pg_settings table.
From this information, we figured that if a Connection has already executed SET x_timeout=y, we should not execute that same statement again. To store a connection's previously used timeout value(s), we added the name of the property and it's value to the clientInfo Property on the Connection.
What we are now seeing is that a "new" Connection from the pool has these values set in its clientInfo, but querying pg_settings (via select setting from pg_catalog.pg_settings where name = x_timeout) on this Connection shows that the Connection does not actually have these values set with the DB. I have "fixed" this in a branch by removing the values from the clientInfo when we close the connection, but I believe that this re-introduces the performance issue since every connection pulled from the pool will need to have the timeout value set again.
We have been working under the assumption that a connection in the pool should still have timeout values set with the DB; so when we get the same connection again, we should not have to set the timeout values again.
The main question, thus, is this: At what point during a Connection's lifecycle do the session-level settings get "reset", or are the session-level settings "clean" (default values) as soon as a Connection is pulled out of the pool? If they are clean on grab, then is it accurate to say that the lifespan of one ProxyConnection is one-to-one with that of the session in the Database (from pool-grab to connection close)?
Bonus question: Where does the "clean" happen? If the Connections come out of the pool clean, then was it Postgres or Hikari that created a new session?
